# Remove HyperLinks from text

Tags: c#, hyperlink, textbox

I need help with it and i'm sure its simple but I cant figure it out.

In my rich text box I copy a link in and I dont want it to be a hyperlink.

So how do I remove the hyperlink?

Comment: try to sanitize it to string ?

Answer (score 10):

It seems you're asking about hyperlinks in the RichTextBox in Windows Forms. If so, it's simply a matter of setting the DetectUrls property to false:

```
richTextBox1.DetectUrls = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string BadInput=Textbox.Text....
string GoodInput=BadInput.Replace("<","&lt;").Replace(">","&gt;");
```

Of course, this is assuming you don't want any HTML to be allowed in the text box.