# C# : Dynamically added Textbox has URL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have written a piece of code in C#.
That is, dynamically adding `TextBox`s to edit data coming from database.
I am getting issues if the data contains URLs.
I need to show the data in textboxs as it is in database, but I am getting appended hyperlinks into the textboxs.

Example :-

Data : My URL :`http://localhost/web/report.aspx?Id=5&code=66634`

Text in the textbox look like below

My URL http://localhost/web/report.aspx?Id=5&code=66634

Could some one please help me why hyperlinks came in my case?

Comment: pavan, this wont happen at all unless the code *linkify* your data. why dont you debug? best, before that, why dont you check your data at db?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HyperLinks from text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359296/remove-hyperlinks-from-text)

Comment: @Alon_A: this is tagged asp.net and rich textbox is a winforms control. and OP has not mentioned about using any thrird party controls. very confused at OP's question.

Comment: @naveen Yeah thanks, question is not fully cleared. That's why its _possible_ dup, though I have a feeling that's what he meant  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to prevent your [rich] textbox from automatically recognizing URLs. If that's the case, simply flip the `DetectUrls` bool:

```
myRichTextBox.DetectUrls = false;
```

Comment: Thanks James : I am using TextBox class, Do I need to set the flag similar to DetectUrls in my case?

Comment: @user1003086, Are you sure you're not using a single-line RichTextBox control? I don't think the TextBox control has the ability to detect URLs.